# Unable to connect Wifi in Mac from Lumia 525

Tags: nokia-lumia-525

Am facing a problem with Wifi connection from my Mac.

When I share mye connection from the Mac (OS version 10.6.8) by going to **System preferences** > **Sharing** > **Internet Sharing**, and try to connect to that WiFi connection from my Windows Phone (running the 8.1 Preview for Developers), each and every time it shows the toast...

> Your phone can`t connect to WiFi network (Mac's Wifi name)

Comment: Didn't understand what exactly you faced. You are trying to connect the WiFi Internet Sharing in the phone from MAC or trying to connect MAC WiFi sharing with the phone?

Comment: Trying to connect MAc WiFi sharing with the phone @VitorCanova

Comment: Can you please improve the question by adding the steps you are taking - and what versions of software is on the Windows Phone and Mac?

Comment: Am explaining the steps which I followed to connect WiFi.Go to `System preferences>Sharing>Checked the internet Sharing option` then in the right side pane window Internet sharing `On` which shows in green color.Then I used my windows phone to connect to WiFi by asusual WiFi connection process.And Version of Windows is `winodws 8.1 (preview for developer options)` and MAC version is `10.6.8`  @NeilTurner

Comment: Does the wifi sharing work with any other device?

Comment: yes it is superbly working in MOTO E and micromax android mobiles. @NeilTurner

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, and then I have removed the security WPA2 and just configured it as a open connection and then I was able to connect my Nokia Lumia 1020.

Looks like Windows mobile 8.1 is not able to communicate with Mac's Wifi when security/encryption is enabled.